# Implementing "liking posts" feature in an app

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a feature that would allow the users to like posts. I have a table in database that keeps track of which people liked which posts. I'm printing the posts on the main page using a "foreach". However, I don't know how I can use the table with the information on who liked which post in order to print some of the posts with an unlike button instead of like button if the user has already liked it. I'd be very glad if you gave some advice.

Comment: It's not a question that can be answered by two or three paragraphs. It would be more efficient to look at some pre-made lib or start doing your work as you can, you could ask a more specific question later.

Answer (score 0):

use user id, post id and like flag in the table
while displaying the post for that user check for the flag with the user id and the post id and according to that display the like or unlike button...

Comment: So does this mean that I can't grab every post at once? I have to print them one by one checking for the information on whether the post was previously liked by the user?

Comment: If you want to grab all the posts that was liked by the particular user then use select postid where userid and like flag